# Formulating simple games as Bayesian problems

Tags: bayesian, risk

Say you are in a game where every win doubles your money and every loss halves. You can walk away any time with the money you have by giving up.

The rules of the game are that at every step you are presented with a problem that has four choices ($1$ to $4$) and one of them is correct. You cannot proceed after wrong guess

Say you have $\$16$ in winnings and you have eliminated $3,4$ leaving with you either to decide on $1$ or $2$ or walk away, and 'you think' there is at least $67\%$ possibility of $1$.

Is there a Bayesian decision formula to make 'correct' decisions?

Comment: Not sufficient information in there! What are those four opttions 1,2,3,4 for instance?

Comment: What do you mean? they are $1,2,3,4$

Comment: Please revise this post as it is unclear what you are asking. We cannot read your mind.

Comment: Is this something like a quiz show where you have to guess (or know) an answer from 4 possible alternatives?

Comment: Your question contains grammatical/English errors. The problem itself does not contain enough information.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala yes it is a quiz I do not understand what makes my formulation unclear

Comment: Can you continue after a wrong answer, too?

Comment: No you are done.